# HTML5 Not Highlighting Invalid Inputs Due To box-shadow

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with inputs with the following Bootstrap class - `form-control`. I use HTML5 form validation on this form. The problem is, the red highlight on the invalid inputs don't appear because of inclusion of `box-shadow`, `border-color` styles.

How can I make them appear even with those styles applied? Some of the styles are applied from my own CSS and some from bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: It would be good if you could show us more code

Comment: its good to post code in jsFiddle.net

Comment: Honestly speaking, that's not always required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the CSS pseudo selectors:

```
input:required:invalid,  
input:focus:invalid, 

textarea:required:invalid,
textarea:focus:invalid

...
```

if necessary you have to specify more powerful CSS selectors like `.form-control`

Comment: Yes, that worked. So all I need to do is use these CSS selectors to define the input's appearance as they would when invalid data is fed into them. Thanks!